# Is it possible to dynamically get the case value from a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way I can dynamically get the case value, so I can use it in a statement?

For example in this basic switch statement:

```
switch(case) {
    case 'A':
       console.log(someCaseValue); // instead of having todo console.log('A')
    break;
}
```

---

### Solution from 4 years later: *(10/18/19)*

I was half asleep when I asked this question and it was a stupid one. However, no questions are stupid in the moment.

This is actually a funny error checking example to test people with, but I digress. ***If you find this post take a rest, or have some tea***

#### PS:

The error is that case is a keyword in the language and can't be a variable name.

Comment: um: `console.log(case);`?

Comment: @Ankit case is the expression in this example. It's a keyword, so it's not valid but I think the expression is what was intended to place inside.

Comment: Wow, I must be tired because it didn't seem to come to mind that I could just call the case value again. :(

Comment: Sorry I went to bed before the limit of when I could accept.

Comment: Upvoted as I had the same question. Reading the answer helped me understand the simplicity of the solution :-) And that I still need to understand more. Questions should be asked otherwise we will not learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by doing...

```
switch(myCase) {
    case 'A':
       console.log(myCase);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, my half awake brain called my switch variable `case`! =P